# AngularJS performance comparison between ng-class on root over multiple ng-if

Tags: angularjs

If I need to use the same conditional in multiple places within one DOM parent, is it better to control this with CSS and `ng-class` (display: none) or use multiple `ng-if` (removes element from DOM but adds more watchers)?

#### Option 1. Multiple `ng-ifs`:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items track by item.id">
    <p ng-if="item.active">Show some active info</p>
    <p>Some general info</p>
    <ul>
        <li ng-if="item.active">Some bullet with active info</li>
        <li>Some bullet with active info</li>
        <li ng-if="item.active">Some bullet with active info</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

#### Option 2. Single `ng-class`:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items track by item.id" ng-class="{'active': item.active}>
    <p class="if-active">Show some active info</p>
    <p>Some general info</p>
    <ul>
        <li class="if-active">Some bullet with active info</li>
        <li>Some bullet with active info</li>
        <li class="if-active">Some bullet with active info</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Together with CSS

```
.if-active {
    display: none;
}

.active .if-active {
    display: default;
}
```

#### Question

Disregarding the above contrived examples and assuming (1) the `ng-repeat` iterates over hundreds of entries and (2) one-time binding of the `active` property isn't possible, is it generally better to add more watchers with `ng-ifs` or add more work on the CSS rendering?

I have not seen this pattern discussed in any of the AngularJS optimization guides I've come across (maybe because it's too obvious).

Answer (score 0):

Each `ngIf` directive adds a watcher to the digest cycle, so it will consume more memory.

Now I don’t know if your `item.active` property is changing during the lifecycle of your application, but if not you could make a directive `ifActive` that effectively removes the element from the DOM tree after a single check.

On the other side, “thousands of entries” will probably blow up your memory usage anyway. I suggest you take a look at “smart” `ngRepeat` alternatives that use virtual scrolling.

Comment: Thanks. I clarified the question to make it clear that this relates to properties that repeatedly change during the lifecycle and only hundreds of entries (agree that thousands probably do not warrant `ngRepeat`). That said, is your belief that adding more watchers with `ngIf` will affect performance more negatively than displaying/hiding multiple elements using CSS?